# How do I go about saving images sent across a JSON API in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, paperclip

Before I code this, I want to make sure that I go about it in the correct way. I have a mobile application that will send an image to the server through a JSON API, preferably as an attribute on the user (or whatever is being imaged).

My current idea is for the mobile application to send the image encoded in Base64, that way it can be included as text on the User resource API calls like so:

```
PUT "/users/1", {"image":"Base64EncodedImageString", "name":"Dan"}
```

But I've read that storing the image in Base64 will make the database too large too fast. So, my plan is to take that string, convert it to an image somehow (I'm sure it will have something to do with the Paperclip gem) and store it in the server's filesystem. The mobile app can then download those images directly through an image MIME type URL, which will be some URL tagged onto the user JSON:

```
{"name":"Dan", "image_url":"http://mysite.com/images/dan.png"}
```

Is this a sound idea?

Comment: Paperclip uses the file upload part of the HTTP POST request. So your API users would have to build the JSON and then attach a file to it, which might be more than what from-the-shelf REST libraries offer.

Comment: Can I not accept a Base64 string, turn it into an image server-side, and then feed it into Paperclip? I don't plan on using the file upload part of the request at all.

Comment: Don't be so paperclip-fixated if you want to hack around it. If you don't: https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+api+image+upload

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use Paperclip or not. I am asking about the process.

Comment: If you're considering storing images on the file system, why Base64 encode? ie - why not use the standard multi-part PUT/POST request for the API?

Comment: Because then I can send the image data along with the normal User calls. With multi-part, they would have to be separate calls, no (say, editing a User's name and uploading an image for example)?